# Geometric proof for why the midpoints of parallel chords of a parabola lie on the same line parallel to the axis

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I was trying to figure out a geometric proof for why the midpoints of parallel chords of a parabola lie on the same line which is parallel to its axis.

I searched on StackExchange and people have mentioned this property but haven't proved it. I was able to prove it algebraically but is there a proof of this property that only uses geometry and various properties of parabolas?

Comment: This is a special case of a general property of conic sections. Look into conjugated diameters of a conic, e.g., http://www.grad.hr/geomteh3d/skripta/konj_promjeri_eng.html.

Comment: This is a special case of pole and polar of a conic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be difficult to find a geometric proof because, once authors have built up the machinery, a projective or analytic proof is easier.

But there is a geometric proof in Taylor's [*Geometry of Conics, 1873, pg 4*](https://archive.org/details/geometryconics01taylgoog/page/n20/mode/2up).  It's reasonably straightforward, but references [Euclid.II.12](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookII/propII12.html), which some of us may be a bit rusty on.

There is also a good discussion on Pamfilos' [Parabola Chords](http://users.math.uoc.gr/%7Epamfilos/eGallery/problems/ParabolaChords.html).  It includes a proof for midpoints.  For some assertions in the proof, refer to the [Parabola](http://users.math.uoc.gr/%7Epamfilos/eGallery/problems/Parabola.html) page.

For convenience, here is a capture of Taylor's proof:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The Taylor's proof is great since it only uses Euclid and properties of the parabola rather than analytic geometry