# A special property when a straight line and a parabola intersect

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, conic-sections

Consider the following graph:

> [image]

The blue line indicates the maximum height from the line to the parabola. Let $P\equiv(x_0,0), Q\equiv(x_m,0)$ and $R\equiv(x_1,0)$. By looking at the coordinates we can find that $PQ=QR$. How can we prove it for the general situation?

(For further:

Parabola $\to y=\sqrt 3 x - \frac{x^2}{20}$

Line $\to y=\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}$

I suppose these equations are not necessary. This is true for any parabola and line as above.)

<sup>(I asked this to get help on a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/651615/305718) on PSE and my own [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/651679/305718) for that)</sup>

Comment: Please care to _not_ use the same symbol (x) for two different things (the variable in equations and the length of a specific segment). And similarly y. This may cause mistakes and misunderstanding.

Comment: This is a well-known property of parabolas, see here for instance: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3791063/geometric-proof-for-why-the-midpoints-of-parallel-chords-of-a-parabola-lie-on-th

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not see it so much as an analytic problem. It is a fundamental geometric property of parabolas. Your equation defines a parabola having a vertical axis. Let $PJ$ be the chord, and let $K$ be the point on the segment furthest from that chord. Construct line $t$, through $K$ and parallel to $PJ$. Let points $Q$ and $R$ lie on the $x$-axis, such that $KQ$ and $JR$ are both vertical, and let $KQ$ meet $PJ$ at point $L$.

Line $t$ can meet the parabola at only the one point. (Otherwise $K$ would not be the furthest point from the chord.) That makes $t$ tangent to the parabola. Line $KQ$ is vertical, making it a diameter of the parabola. Any chord parallel to $t$ is bisected by this diameter, so $L$ is the midpoint of $PJ$. This bisection property was covered by Archimedes in *Quadrature of the Parabola* (Proposition 1), and by Apollonius in *Conica* (I,46).

[image]

Line $KLQ$ is parallel to $JR$ and bisects $PJ$, so it must also bisect $PR$. That makes $Q$ the midpoint of $PR$.

Answer (score 6):

The maximum distance from parabola to the line is at the point where the tangent to parabola is parallel to the line. The line's slope is $1/\sqrt 3$ and the derivative of the function defining a parabola: $$y=\sqrt 3 x - x^2/20$$ is $$y'= \sqrt 3 - x/10$$
which equals $1/\sqrt 3$ at $$x_m=10(\sqrt 3 - \tfrac 1{\sqrt 3})$$

The intersection of line and parabola is at $x$ where $$\sqrt 3 x - x^2/20 = \frac x{\sqrt3}$$ which yields $$x_0=0$$ or $$x_1=20(\sqrt3 - \tfrac 1{\sqrt 3})$$
hence $$x_m = \frac 12 x_1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not a good thing to prove for a numerical example, I am here trying to prove it for a general situation, **being inspired by the other answers**.

Let the equations of parabola and straight line be
$$y=ax^2+bx+c \tag{1}$$ and
$$y=px+q \tag{2}$$
respectively.

Quoting [CiaPan's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4200301/947379),

> The maximum distance from parabola to the line is at the point where the tangent to parabola is parallel to the line.

The derivative of the function of parabola is,
$$y'=2ax+b$$

then,
$$p=2ax_m+b$$
$$x_m =\frac{(p-b)}{2a}\tag{A}$$

From (1) and (2) we get,
$$ax^2+(b-p)x+(c-q)=0$$
Roots of this equation give $x$-coordinates of the points of intersection of parabola and chord.
Assuming this has real roots let's find the sum of two roots:
$$\begin{align}x_0 + x_1 &= \frac{-(b-p)}{a}\\
&=\frac{(p-b)}{a}\tag{B}\end{align}$$

What we have to prove is $$x_m=\frac{x_0 + x_1 }{2}$$
Hence proved from (A) and (B).